# AngularJs not loading sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

I am running a very basic program in angularjs but don't know why the script is not loading
the evaluation tags are displayed on the view page.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the program?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
     <html ng-app='myApp'>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

      </head>
     <body ng-controller='CartController'>
     <h1>Your Order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
   <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
   <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
  <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
  <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
   </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function CartController($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
  {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: '8', price: '3.95'},
  {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: '17', price: '12.95'},
  {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: '5', price: '6.95'}
   ];
 $scope.remove = function(index) {
 // splice is an ECMA javascript function
$scope.items.splice(index, 1);
   }
   }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I tried this code, this runs fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
    Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newcontact"/>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>

 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
   </ul>

 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function ContactController($scope) {
    $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

    $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
    $scope.newcontact = "";
    }
}
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You have whitespaces in your angular script url.

Comment: sorry it happened while copying the code here, in the editor the url is fine. I've even corrected it here

Comment: You are still missing `http:` in your url.

Comment: The double slash uses the current protocol, ie http or http. Have you tried setting your doctype to just html (HTML5 spec)

Comment: tried with that too doesn't work; tried with all the permutation combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
<html ng-app='myApp' >
```

to this

```
<html ng-app >
```

You don't have a module called `'myApp'`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwcz4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help removing the module name worked from ng-app. I appreciate it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare your angular app. Try that:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('CartController',function CartController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: '8', price: '3.95'},
    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: '17', price: '12.95'},
    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: '5', price: '6.95'}
    ];
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        // splice is an ECMA javascript function
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
 });
```